# Display products of particular catagory in magento 2 cms page

Tags: magento2.2

How to display products of a particular category on cms page.

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps to add any category's products on CMS page.

- Navigate to your CMS page in admin and Insert Widget.
- Select **Catalog Product List** in Widget Type.
- Select **Category** in conditions.